# "METRICS.E.HIS_Metriken___Number_of_Paths_PATH__CR_MET5_" warning in Klocwork

Tags: klocwork

I'm getting this warning in Klocwork

```
METRICS.E.HIS_Metriken___Number_of_Paths_PATH__CR_MET5_
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The error message "METRICS.E.HIS_Metriken___Number_of_Paths_PATH__CR_MET5_" in Klocwork is related to a metric called "Number of Paths" which is calculated for a function or method. This metric counts the number of possible execution paths through the code, which can help to estimate the complexity and potential for errors in the code.

The error message suggests that the "Number of Paths" metric has exceeded a certain threshold, which is specified by the CR_MET5 parameter. This threshold may be set by your organization's coding standards or by Klocwork's default settings.

Exceeding this threshold may indicate that the code is overly complex and difficult to understand or maintain, or that there may be a higher likelihood of errors or bugs. It is recommended to review the code and consider refactoring or simplifying it to reduce its complexity and improve its readability and maintainability.